# Adding UI Tests in Unit testing target

Tags: earlgrey

I don't want to pollute/mix the unit test cases(written using QuickSpec) which I have written in **UNIT TESTING TARGET** with UI tests from EarlGrey.

Is there any alternative that I can have EarlGrey tests to be added to **UI TESTING TARGET**?

Answer (score 0):

EG 2 is currently in the process of being released which allows you to add EarlGrey tests in a UI Testing target. Please stay tuned on the slack channel for more information.

Comment: Does it support stubbing the Restful API request/response so that I can check UI behavior?